# Different animations for Jquery ui tabs

Tags: jquery-ui

I'm using jquery ui tabs widget. I've not used a jquery theme as i prefer to do my own css and stuff. I've got it working, but what i'd like is to have a different animation effect for the tab content when a different tab is clicked. What i'd like is for the new tab content to slide in from the left.

At the moment i have:

```
$("#tabs").tabs({ fx: {slide: 'slow' } }); });
```

I know the code above is just slide and not slide left but it doesn't even do a slide!
I have downloaded the slide effects as part of my custom ui download. I don't know why it isn't working! Is it some css that i'm lacking?! I don't know!!!

Comment: No! I've tried all sorts of things and had a look at the jquery ui download to make sure that i've downloaded the right stuff. Whatever effect i ask it to perform, it just does the same thing, hide old content, show new.

Comment: Here is the link to jQueryUI Tabs widget documentation http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#option-show And the list of jQueryUI animation effects https://jqueryui.com/effect/

Answer (score 9):

Not sure which version you use, but with 1.7.1 here is how to do it:

```
$("#tabs").tabs({ 
    fx: { height: 'toggle', duration: 'slow' }
});
```

Comment: but for specific toggle animation?

Answer (score 3):

i know this question is older than a year, but you can try this one:

```
$('#tabs').tabs(
{
   fx: { width: 'toggle', duration: '500' }
});
```

if you use 'width' jQuery will create the effect using width property, hence a horizontal animation. you can also use height and width together for a diagonal effect.

also try 'hide' and 'show' keywords instead of 'toggle', they're cool too :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one: http://www.eduteka.org/ajax/tabs3/
for more options

Answer (score 0):

Just to update the answer to this question, using version 1.10 of jquery ui, I used the 'show' option to apply a transition effect on the tabs. There is an example in the jquery ui documentation here:

http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#option-show

```
$( ".selector" ).tabs({ show: { effect: "blind", duration: 800 } });
```