# JQuery Tabs - Toggle Animations

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui

So far I have this code

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $(".slidetabs").tabs(".images > div", {
        effect: "fade",
        rotate: true,
        autoplay: true
    }).slideshow();

    $(".slidetabs").data("slideshow").play();
});
```

Is there any way to have different animation? Not cross-fade, but something else. fx{} doesn't work for me and I don't know why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

effect seems to work for jQuery TOOLS-variant of tabs. You're sure you're not using that?
http://flowplayer.org/tools/tabs/index.html#effects <-custom effects in that case.

If this is about jQuery UI, this is a dupe: [Different animations for Jquery ui tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/910640/different-animations-for-jquery-ui-tabs)
(though that one is a bit old, it still gives the right answer afaik).