# Jquery UI effects don't work

Tags: jquery, user-interface

I'm using latest version of both `jQuery` and `jQuery UI` scripts, the problem is that actually can't set any `div` to animate using UI effects (toggle, slide, opacity, etc.).

```
$('#tabs').tabs( {
    fx: [ { 
        opacity:'toggle', 
        duration:'normal'
    },   // hide option
    {   opacity:'toggle',
        duration:'fast'
    }]
}); // show option
```

The UI tabs works, but don't make any animation when I add the fx parameters. It just shows or hides the tabs, but with no animation at all.

Just downloaded the latest versions today, for the UI have downloaded a custom bundle including ALL the things (effects included, of course).

Don't know if I must use a different bundle.

Answer (score 1):

Your bundle is most likely correct. I'd extract the bundle again and take a look at the index.html to see how they call the effects.

Comment: This is my code:

**
$("#years").tabs({ fx: { height: 'toggle' } });
**

Comment: Just trying to add some animation to every tab change.

Comment: Ooooo sorry I misunderstood it for a second.

$("#tabs").tabs({ 
    fx: { height: 'toggle', duration: 'slow' }
});


Found on another Stackoverflow page: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/910640/different-animations-for-jquery-ui-tabs

Comment: Didn't work. I'm going to try to make a div toggle, outside the tabs div.
EDIT: Outside of the tabs div, the Jquery animation effects work. But not when they are inside the tabs. 
At least I can't get it to work.